# How to run selenium tests on Docker for Windows

Tags: java, windows, selenium, docker

I've started a Udemy curse for testers about using Docker to run Selenium scripts. All simple and apparently easy but the scripts that should run in the pre-build containers Selenium standalone with Chrome or wth Firefox both fail...:
The script:

```
package docker;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class DockerWithChrome {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException {
        ChromeOptions cap = new ChromeOptions();
        cap.setHeadless(true);
        //cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Chrome" );

        RemoteWebDriver driver;
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
        System.out.println("Title of the Home page:" + driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }
}`
```

And the result:

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "server:CONFIG_UUID": "30eb3a22-af38-4fa4-9698-8cef0b36ea4c",
    "goog:chromeOptions": {
      "args": [
        "--headless",
        "--disable-gpu"
      ],
      "extensions": [
      ]
    }
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "goog:chromeOptions": {
          "args": [
            "--headless",
            "--disable-gpu"
          ],
          "extensions": [
          ]
        },
        "server:CONFIG_UUID": "30eb3a22-af38-4fa4-9698-8cef0b36ea4c"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The same happens on Chrome and Firefox.
I'm a beginner in using Docker and so far is useless for me if I can't run Selenium tests... Please advice!!

The OS is: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Version  10.0.17763 Build 17763

Raluca

Comment: You might want to share a small repo and your Dockerfile in order to recreate your issue.

Comment: Dockerfile contents: <from selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome:latest>